# Leaflet: How to add Title (HoverText) to a custom defined icon?

Tags: leaflet

My icon is defined as

```
var IconGREEN = new L.Icon({
iconUrl: '/Path/filename.svg',
iconSize:    [40, 40],
iconAnchor:  [10, 10],
popupAnchor: [10, -10]});
```

It is used in the map several times like

```
var icon01 = L.marker([41.5, 17.4], {icon: IconGREEN}).addTo(Map).bindPopup("Icon green<br><br><A href='https://stackoverflow.com/' target='_parent'>URL</A>");
```

For normal markers, a title, working as HoverText, can be added like *{title: 'Hover Text'}*.

(How) can I add indivual titles for each usage of the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the title to the options:

```
var icon01 = L.marker([41.5, 17.4], {icon: IconGREEN, title: 'title 1'}).addTo(Map).bindPopup("Icon green<br><br><A href='https://stackoverflow.com/' target='_parent'>URL</A>");

var icon02 = L.marker([41.5, 17.4], {icon: IconGREEN, title: 'title 2'}).addTo(Map).bindPopup("Icon green<br><br><A href='https://stackoverflow.com/' target='_parent'>URL</A>");
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! Tried it similar but at a wrong location. Any hint, where to find such infomation by myself?

Comment: In the [Docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html) or in the [Tutorials](https://leafletjs.com/examples.html)

Comment: OK, checked both yetserday, but did not get it.